# Iterating through all documents or objects in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

What is the command for displaying the n-th object/document in MongoDB?

Say I have 4000 objects stored in the database, and I want to loop through all 4000 of these objects to apply commands to them, I would do something like this:

```
for(i=0;db.foo.count();i++){
    do something
}
```

What should `i` be, with `i` being the first index. How do I iterate through all objects in MongoDB?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you intend to do to these objects, what are the commands you want to be applied?

Comment: The explanation is a bit long. I am trying to compare the items in HTTP headers which I requested with another script between two collections. The first collection would be a scrape that runs today. The second collection would be a scrape that runs in two months. There are 4000 or so of these objects with the `url` as the `_id`. What I am trying to attempt is compare the header objects in two months.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the signature to `find` queries.

```
var cursor = collection.find(query, [fields], options);
cursor.sort(fields).limit(n).skip(m).each(function(err, doc) {});
```

For accessing n-th object use `skip`. Or for a batch after n-th object you can use `limit` and `skip`. For a large collection use `stream`.

Comment: Ah, cool. So this iterates through all objects with the `skip` command, which I presume is placed with-in the curly brace?

Comment: Can you please provide an example on how I could use skip() to loop through the first object, execute code, then move onto the second, execute code, move onto third, execute code, etc?

Comment: To look at code snippets have a look at https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Comment: Thank you. Are (n) and (m) values I change to suite my needs?

Comment: Yup, you set them as per your needs :)